# I am not getting correct data continuosly from string buffer

Tags: java, string, sockets, buffer

i am getting data from hyper terminal through socket, my question is while i am typing the data continously (the same letter like 'aaaa') it will be converted to aaáa. The third letter is changed to some other format. please provide the solution ..

```
SocketChannel sChannel = (SocketChannel)selKey.channel();
ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
sChannel.read(bb);
bb.flip();
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
String str=decoder.decode(bb).toString();
StringBuffer sb = (StringBuffer)selKey.attachment();
sb.append( str );
bb.clear( );

String line = sb.toString();
if ((line.indexOf("\n") != -1) || (line.indexOf("\r") != -1)) 
{
    sb.delete(0,sb.length());
    System.out.print(line);
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: java.. third character is changing..

Comment: I have added the `java` tag to your question.  Please, in future, provide the language you are using, as this will help you actually get an answer.

Comment: thank u.. i will follow it.. please provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

Characterset encoding differences perhaps?

To check what your JVM uses: `Charset.defaultCharset()`

What uses your hyper terminal?

...you should ideally also provide the code, a reproducible example, on how you read the data. Btw, I don't know anything about "hyper terminals" but are you sure this client never inserts check bits or such kind of things in the stream?

Comment: no, just third character is varying and next two same and again third character for same letter entering..default is windows 1252.